# Hand-held programmable device needed

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

Hopefully this question is not too off-topic for this board. I need a ready-made programmable hand-held device with an ethernet-connection. Something like an Arduino with batteries and display and some buttons in a box.
This is for my company so a complete ground-up assembly is too expensive and time-consuming in this case. Any hints to companies that produce something like this are welcome. And yes, I tried searching with different search-engines already. :-)
Thanks for your time!

Comment: And what is the purpose of this device? Connect to ethernet and.... intercept and analyse the traffic? Why does it need to be handheld when it is going to be wired? With PoE you don't even need a battery.

Comment: A Leonardo ETH with a keypad shield and a printed box perhaps?
Use PoE or two 18650 cells for power supply.

Comment: Use a cheap or preowned laptop with linux and wireshark.

Comment: try raspberry pi 3, it comes with all the features you needed. You need to take care of battery part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no opinion about this hardware (I don't own it) so please treat my answer as information only. When I was searching through web I found [M5Stack](https://m5stack.com/)

It looks like hardware made for IoT development.
It has a LCD and 3 buttons and think it can be programmed using ArduinoIDE.
It's designed that you can design any hardware you want and "stack" the device on top of it. Found if available to buy from China for below 30USD.

[image: M5Stack parts]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2es-l4z2Zg

Comment: That's a really nice find, and what looks to be a fantastic module. I'm going to have to get myself one to play with and port DisplayCore to - and of course provide full support in UECIDE...

Comment: I thought that there might be an Arduino-based solution for my task, that's why I chose this board for my question. I'm sorry if I wasted a bit of you time and will take the answers I got so far as a starting point. Thanks to those who commented!